# Last row inserted in QTableWidget looks different

Tags: qt

I have a QtableWidget. When an "Add" button is clicked, I added a new row to the table. The cells each row contain some custom widgets.

```
void addRow() {
    tableWidget->insertRow(tableWidget->rowCount());
    int itemRow = tableWidget->rowCount() - 1;
    // create custom widgets for each column
    tableWidget->setCellWidget(itemrow, columnNumber, customWidget);
}
```

Everything works fine. The only problem is that the last row that is seems to have slightly different size/margin/padding etc. So the widgets in each column are slightly misaligned compared to the previous rows.

When another row is added, what was previously the last row now appears fine. Its always the last row added, that "looks" slightly different.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/hTWf]

Is there something I need to do after adding the row?

Comment: Not sure what's going on, if you've got a testcase it would be great if you could submit a bug report. On the other hand, I'm pretty sure that you're not supposed to add that many **widgets** into an item view. Why are you adding widgets in every row?

Comment: That might be some row selection effect can you try to make the the items not select-able

Comment: Already doing table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);